# Unable to get iframe using Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iframe, cheerio

Hi I am trying to get an iframe from [wathfree.to](http://www.watchfree.to/watch-366-Forrest-Gump-movie-online-free-putlocker.html).

Here is the code I am using for this purpose:

```js
function getSecondBody(url2)
{
    url2 = 'http://www.watchfree.to/watch-366-Forrest-Gump-movie-online-free-putlocker.html';
    request(url2, function(err, resp, body)
{
 var $  = cheerio.load(body);
    
 var embedcode = $('.links_left_container');
  embedcodetext2 = embedcode.html();
 console.log(embedcodetext2);
 return embedcodetext2;
});
}
```

But response returned doesn't contain the iframe that I need.

here is the response I am receiving:

[image: response on console]

while the actual page looks like this:
[image: orignal page]

Only the iframe part is missing in my response.

Comment: what do you want to get from this html code? video link?
The iframe has been append to  DOM by javascript, you can see all html what cheerio can craw by way view source of page (Ctrl + U for chrome) and go to line 72 or find with keyword #player_frame, you will see how it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view-source:http://www.watchfree.to/watch-366-Forrest-Gump-movie-online-free-putlocker.html`

Please take a look the source of the page. There is no iframe. It's generic content. So when you request it, it won't load to DOM.

You need to crawl probably this line if you want openload embed link:

```
var locations = ["http:\/\/streamin.to\/embed-k2msgp8yhhd8-580x326.html","http:\/\/streamin.to\/embed-cbp8zxw3yo3f-580x326.html","http:\/\/embed.nowvideo.sx\/embed.php?v=2729070a4365a","http:\/\/thevideo.me\/embed-wm815ejm5uvb-580x326.html","https:\/\/estream.to\/embed-6u49dntawgr0.html","http:\/\/thevideo.me\/embed-n14mh2bjj2nz-580x326.html","http:\/\/vidtodo.com\/embed-bmjw5u1e18js.html","http:\/\/vidtodo.com\/embed-z8614uxy1824.html","https:\/\/openload.co\/embed\/xTLPXjSGz7o\/","https:\/\/openload.co\/embed\/F8gJS5Y1o1o\/"];
```

Comment: can you specify the location of this line ?

Comment: @NaveedKhan 51.